# programming to capture input in an array

Tags: java

I am trying to write a java program that prompts the user to enter 5 names.  These names need to be stored in an array.  Once the 5th name is entered, the program will automatically print the results back to the user.  I am having problems getting my scanner working to capture the user's input when they type the name.

This is what I have so far:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter name 1: ");
String name 1 = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: That won't compile as the last line is not even a Java statement.

Comment: If you clarify the actual issue (error messages and such) we can help you more. With the code provided I pointed out the one issue I saw, but there might be more.

Answer (score 2):

`String name 1 = input.nextLine();` won't work because there is a space between name and 1. It needs to be `String name1 = input.nextLine();`

Here is a complete example:

```
String[] names = new String[5];
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter name number " + i + ".");
    names[i] = in.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("Names entered:");

for (int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
    System.out.println(names[i]);
}
```

Comment: The OP requires an array, as the original question reads (as of 00:52:20 UTC)

Answer (score 1):

this is what you are looking for

```
    String[] names = new String[5];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        names[i] = in.nextLine();
    }
    for (String string : names) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```